# SwiftUI : How to set image in MacOs?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, xcode11

please help me to set image in macOs application using swiftUI

Here is my Implementation:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SigninView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Image("Profile")
        .resizable()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
  }
}
```

but image is not visible in View

[image: Image in not visible in view]

Comment: And what's wrong? Your "Profile" image just should be in Assets catalog.

Comment: image is not display

Comment: What image format is Profile image? I tried several and all work except BMP. Check your resources.

Comment: It has to be in *Assets.xcassets* catalog and named just "Profile" for your `Image("Profile")` worked.

Comment: In Assets.xcassets name is "Profile" but still it not working

Comment: Can't be. Are you sure `SigninView` is added in view hierarchy of window?

Comment: yes,
frame size will be covered in view but image in not display

Comment: If you go to your Assets catalog, click on the image and in the Inspectors panel "Show Attributes Inspector" (just type this in the help to find where it is). Is the "Render As" attribute set to "Original Image"?

Comment: I'm also try this. but still not working @Nycen

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct SigninView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Image("Profile") // this is image name from xcassets
     // Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.folderName) ?? NSImage()) // method for system image 
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
        .clipped()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .padding()
    }
  }
}
```